# How to redo the cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport virtual scrolling component

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

**problem**
hiding the address bar in mobile browsers does not work when scrolling the page

**why does not it work**
Hiding the address bar in a mobile browser is triggered on scrolling when the page size is larger than the viewport, this is standard browser behavior.
At the moment, the application is built like this: the page size is equal to the viewport size (screen size), so there is no scrolling on the page => the page does not scroll => hiding the address bar will not work

**What solution do I see**
Resize the page to fit the ribbon (cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport).
Remove scrolling in the feed.
When scrolling the page, emulate events called when scrolling the ribbon (cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport)

**that does not work**
I can't emulate events triggered when scrolling the tape